# TypeError: cars.map is not a function - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, crud

I'm trying to get all data into a table and I'm using reactjs and hooks to implement CRUD so I gott this error please can someone help me to fix this issue.

Here is the code :

```
const [car, setCarh] = useState(initialState)

  useEffect(()=> {
      retrieveCars();
      
    }, [])

    const retrieveCars =() =>{
      DataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        
         setCarh(response.data) 
       
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
       
    }
<tbody>
                {
                  cars.map((data) => (
                    <tr >
                    
                    <th scope="row">{data.idCars}</th>  
                  
                  <td>{data.carName}</td>
                  <td>{data.carModel}</td>
                  <td>
                  <Link to={"/classement/update/" + data.idCars}
                    className="btn btn-info"
                    >
                    Edit
                   </Link>
```

[image]

Comment: How have you you defined initialState? make sure it's an array

Comment: @ErfanNaghashlou   const initialState = {
        idCars: null,
        carName: "",
        carModel: ""
      };

Comment: Try console logging car and see if it's actually an array

Comment: @Petar18 here is the console log 0: {idCars: 97, carName: 'Tiguan', carModel: 'Volkswagen'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially, you define cars as an object:

```
 initialState = { idCars: null, carName: "", carModel: "" }
```

objects don't have a map method.

if you are going to show data of more than one car, you need to create an array and fill it with objects, each representing a car.

if you want to show data of a single car, you don't need to use map. for example:

```
    const [car, setCar] = useState(initialState)

         return (<tr >
                
                <th scope="row">{car.carName}</th>  
              
              <td>{data.carModel}</td>
              <td></tr> ....
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this : const [cars, setCarhs] = useState([]); and it works